# Plotting a grouped pandas data in plotly bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
Country  Sold
 Japan   3432
 Japan   4364
 Korea   2231
 India   1130
 India   2342
  USA    4333
  USA    2356
  USA    3423
```

I want to plot graphs using this dataframe. The plot will have country names on `X-axis` and the `mean/sum` of the sold of each country will on `y-axis`. I know I can compute the mean/sum using the group by function like this:

```
df.groupby('Country')['Sold'].mean()
```

I know the plotly histogram has the function that can directly compute the value and plot the graph. But I want to apply on other graph of `plotly` such as `bar chart` to make the graph more interactive. I am having a hard time figuring it out. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Please, make your question clear. Do you want a bar chart where x are countries and y are sums for each country?